# Extending a model in mobx state tree

Tags: mobx-state-tree

I have a bunch of stores each containing a list of one entity type like

```
const userStore = EntityStore.create(....)

const supplierStore = EntityStore.create(....)
```

Some stores can offer additional functionalities, so I wrote

```
const orderStore = EntityStore
.views(self => ({
    allByUserId: branchId => ....)
}))
.create(....)
```

So far, everything was fine, but now I wanted to create a "store manager" containing a list of all such stores and it failed with a message like

> Error: [mobx-state-tree] Error while converting ...
>   value of type EntityStore: (id: Order)> is not assignable to type: `EntityStore`,
>   expected an instance of `EntityStore` or a snapshot like ... instead
>   (Note that a snapshot of the provided value is compatible with the targeted type)

The message is clear, my "EntityStore with views" is not of the same type as an "EntityStore". But it's an extension of it, so I wonder if there's a declaration allowing it. Something like `List<? extends EntityStore>` in Java?

Or a nice workaround allowing me to add the additional functionality to `EntityStore` without changing its type?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. You can't. Because `.views()` (as basically any other dot method) creates [a whole new](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/blob/7eb973c454d277e189a89855c926218d2391ff80/packages/mobx-state-tree/src/types/complex-types/model.ts#L381) `ModelType` object every time you invoke it.

What you could do instead is use a `union` type:

> - `types.union(options?: { dispatcher?: (snapshot) => Type, eager?:
>     boolean }, types...)` create a union of multiple types. If the correct
>     type cannot be inferred unambiguously from a snapshot, provide a
>     dispatcher function to determine the type. When eager flag is set to
>     true (default) - the first matching type will be used, if set to false
>     the type check will pass only if exactly 1 type matches.

There's also an example below of how to [simulate inheritance by using type composition](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree#simulate-inheritance-by-using-type-composition):

```
const Square = types
    .model(
        "Square",
        {
            width: types.number
        }
    )
    .views(self => ({
        surface() {
            return self.width * self.width
        }
    }))

// create a new type, based on Square
const Box = Square
    .named("Box")
    .views(self => {
        // save the base implementation of surface
        const superSurface = self.surface

        return {
            // super contrived override example!
            surface() {
                return superSurface() * 1
            },
            volume() {
                return self.surface * self.width
            }
        }
    }))

// no inheritance, but, union types and code reuse
const Shape = types.union(Box, Square)
```

So, **no inheritance, but, union types and code reuse**.